# Integrating FlowXO with twilio

Tags: twilio, chat, twilio-api

How can one create a bot in Flow.xo that listens to twilio messages? In other words can I write a bot in FlowXO to send and receive SMS messages from my twilio account?

Flow.XO allows one to send SMS messages via their twilio integration function, but it only has two functions:

1> Twilio calls

2> Twilio SMS messages

Both these are outward bound, and we can only send messages (calls, or SMS) via twilio from Flow.xo. Can I receive messages in FlowspellingXO from Twilio too? How is this accomplished?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I haven't used Flow.XO before, but a quick look through the documentation suggests that this is the guide for you: https://support.flowxo.com/article/152-creating-a-twilio-sms-bot

Going through that process will create a URL that you will apply to your Twilio number or messaging service. That URL is the webhook URL that Twilio will use to send details about incoming messages so that your bot can respond to replies from your user.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: twilio allows you to integrate 2 way messaging, in a seamless way, The URL it provides for POST is provided by twilio too. So, this means that when i send a message to a phone number from Flow XO - all is well, the message passes through fine. The problem is on the Flow XO side - when I want to receive messages in FLow from twilio, There is provision in Flow with the help of  a webhook to a GET, just this part is broken, or unclear how to integrate. Flow needs a URL for that GET, can I get the URL for a GET from twilio?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re saying here, FlowXO needs to provide a url that you add to your Twilio number. That way when someone else sends a message to your Twilio number it will be passed on to FlowXO. Have you followed the link above? What have you tried so far? What isn’t working? Feel free to update your question with screenshots or code.

Comment: yes,you are correct twilio needs a URL from FlowXO,  All that was done correctly, and the webhook did fire when twilio received an incoming message. But on certain numbers, the webhook would not fire, twilio themselves are trying out various carriers.

Comment: ..contd.. Evven did factory resets, and changed SIM on phone but no use on those incommunicado numbers. Suspect that the SMSC does not accept an IP address, or the IP address used by the carrier is not registered n twilios; side(even a port num is required for this). BTW the SMSC is a carrier number that is for SMS messaging. Twilio support still hasnt come back as writing.

Comment: If you are having trouble receiving messages then you will need to follow up with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). That's not something we are going to solve on Stack Overflow.

Comment: update, the error of not being able to  create flows in FlowXO went away when we changed the twilio number that was used for setting up the chatbot -  the problem was to do with SMS messages being blocked by twilio.